# OR statement in DB::table?

Tags: laravel

How can I apply this condition

```
$where =  "id={$get->id} or ref_id={$get->ref_id}";
```

To DB::table ?

Maybe something like

```
 DB::table("transaction")->where("id",$get->id)->or("ref_id",$get->ref_id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `orWhere`:

```
 DB::table("transaction")->where("id",$get->id)->orWhere("ref_id",$get->ref_id);
```

Thanks..!